# Carouselview with SkiaSharp

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, skiasharp

I am trying to set a template to carousel view that contains SkiaSharp. I can't set Source on the skia:SKCanvasView so I created a template view but now nothing gets displayed as I am binding the carousel view to ImageResults but I don't know how to add the template to the list?

```
public List<Resultlist> ImageResults = new List<Resultlist>();
      public  class Resultlist
        {
            public string Desc { get; set; }
    
            public string Value { get; set; }
    
            public  SKBitmap foto { get; set; }
        }
```

```
<CarouselView Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Never"  Style="{StaticResource ImageResultCarousel}" 
                ItemsSource="{Binding ImageResults, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                 BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource PictureBackground}"
                                   >
                            <CarouselView.ItemTemplate >
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <resultlist:template></resultlist:template>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
</CarouselView>
```

Template

```
<yummy:PancakeView  CornerRadius="80">
            <skia:SKCanvasView  x:Name="canvasView" HeightRequest="400"  WidthRequest="200"
        PaintSurface="OnCanvasViewPaintSurface" />
     </yummy:PancakeView >
```

back of my template

```
SKBitmap bitmap =
    BitmapExtensions.LoadBitmapResource(typeof(template),
                                        "Resultlist.Screenshot.png");

    private void OnCanvasViewPaintSurface(object sender, SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs args)
    {
        SKImageInfo info = args.Info;
        SKSurface surface = args.Surface;
        SKCanvas canvas = surface.Canvas;

        canvas.Clear();

        SKRect dest = new SKRect(0, 0, info.Width, info.Height);

        BitmapStretch stretch = (BitmapStretch)BitmapStretch.AspectFill;
        BitmapAlignment horizontal = (BitmapAlignment)BitmapAlignment.Center;
        BitmapAlignment vertical = (BitmapAlignment)BitmapAlignment.Center;

        canvas.DrawBitmap(bitmap, dest, stretch, horizontal, vertical);
    }
```

Comment: you do not appear to be doing anything to bind your data to your template

Comment: I am not sure how

Comment: using a `"{Binding}"` expression like you do with any templated control

Comment: but there is no item source on SKCanvasView

Comment: <yummy:PancakeView  CornerRadius="80">
       <skia:SKCanvasView  x:Name="canvasView" HeightRequest="400"  WidthRequest="200" BindingContext="{Binding foto}" doesn't work 
         />
     </yummy:PancakeView >

Answer (score 0):

We can create inline "View" in DataTemplate.

```
<CarouselView Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Never"  Style="{StaticResource ImageResultCarousel}" 
                ItemsSource="{Binding ImageResults, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                 BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource PictureBackground}"
                                   >
                            <CarouselView.ItemTemplate >
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <yummy:PancakeView  CornerRadius="80">
            <skia:SKCanvasView  x:Name="canvasView" HeightRequest="400"  WidthRequest="200"
        PaintSurface="OnCanvasViewPaintSurface" />
     </yummy:PancakeView >
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
</CarouselView>
```

and in code behind

```
private void OnCanvasViewPaintSurface(object sender, SkiaSharp.Views.Forms.SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs e)
        {
            var canvasView = sender as SKCanvasView;
            var resultList = canvasView.BindingContext as Resultlist;
            //Now we can use resultList.foto to draw canvas.
        }
```